# Android application to watch Youtube videos with acceleration and popularity sorting features?

Tags: android, video, media-player, youtube, play-store

I watch a lot of videos on Youtube. But in official app on Google Play some essential features that I need are not presented. But they are presented on their website.

- Possibility to watch/play videos at accelerated speed (e.g. x1.5 or x2)
- Sort videos on some Youtube channel based on popularity.

---

I'm looking for **free** **Android** application that can be used on smartphones/tablets. Is there some app that allows watching most popular videos (on some channel) and allows watching at accelerated speed?